# Inconsistency in ANCOVA results between rstatix and car

Tags: r, ancova, contrasts

I am trying to run an ANCOVA in R with a binary treatment variable, a continuous covariate, and their interaction (response ~ cont*bin). My understanding has always been that AN(C)OVA and regression are based on the same underlying model. In line with this, if I apply Anova() from the car package to a linear regression object, then the resulting p-values are the same as for the original regression.

However, if I use the anova_test() function from the rstatix package, the p-value and F statistic for the main effect of the continuous variable are different than those obtained using the Anova() function (the interaction and the main effect of the binary treatment are the same in all models). I am using type 3 sums of squares in both cases.

Why do these p-values differ? I am aware that anova_test() in rstatix uses orthogonal contrasts, whereas Anova() uses treatment contrasts (see this post by the rstatix package author: https://github.com/kassambara/rstatix/issues/74). However, I do not understand what this means when calculating F statistics for a continuous variable.

Here is a minimal working example:

```
set.seed(123)

bin <- rbinom(100, 1, 0.5) # binary treatment
cont <- rnorm(100, 0, 1) # continuous covariate

response <- 3*cont + 5*bin + 2*cont*bin + rnorm(100, 0, 20)

data <- data.frame(cont, bin = as.factor(bin), response)

reg.model <- lm(response ~ cont*bin, data = data)
summary(reg.model)

library(car)
Anova(reg.model, type = "III")

library(rstatix)
anova_test(response ~ cont*bin, data = data, type = 3)
```

I would be grateful for any help!